# how to set model value with view element text in javascript (MVC 4)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to have my model to be set by a value of a view element.
And then call a method in the controller with the model attribute value as parameter in javascript.

whats the best way of doing this?

something like:

```
@Model.Attribute = $(ElementId).val(); //<- how can I do this?

'@Html.Action("GetPeople", new { id = @Model.Attribute})';
```

I've been investigating and I cannot find a way of doing this.
I read and tried  binding between view and model. but when i call @Model.Attribute the value is always default.  Even if I change the textbox value and the model attribute does not change.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Code, new { id = "txtAttribute"})
```

I did the model attribute binding in the Controller as you can see

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new MyModel();
            View("Default", model);
        }
```

I've tried multiple things but they all failed

```
var modelattribute = '@Model.Attribute';
modelattribute = '@ViewData["ModelAttribute"]';
modelattribute = '@Html.Raw(Model.Attribute)'
modelattribute = '@Html.raw(json.encode(Model.Attribute))'
```

is this possible? or do i have to change my algorithm?

**UPDATE: my model code**

```
public class MyModel
{

    public string Attribute{ get; set; }


}
```

Thanks a lot,
Nelssen

Comment: Can you  post your model code?

Comment: I don't think you can bind a value from HTML to the MVC's Model. You have to use JS to set it or ajax.

Comment: Hello  WookieCoder, My model is quite simple. you can check now

Comment: Hello DontVotemeDown, how can i set it through js or ajax? like a ajax call with data parameter to that method?

Comment: I said bs, maybe ajax is not the case, but I would be on setting it through javascript, actually.

Comment: Razor code is parsed on the server before its sent to the view. Once on the client, your model does not exist (you cant set its properties using javascript/jquery). In your script you need to build a url based on the textbox value and use ajax to call a method that returns a partial view and update the DOM (or use `location.href=yourUrl` is you want to redirect).

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: No need to sorry, I learn something from it. Do you think that there is a way of achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of a javascript variable from your model liks so: `var modelattribute = "@Model.Attribute";`
As for getting your model data to your controller, by far the easiest way is to use hidden form elements:

```
//JAVASCRIPT
function postDataToController() {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("action", "submitFormData");
    var hiddenElement = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenElement.setAttribute("name","attributeName");
    $(hiddenElement).val("attribute value");
    $(form).append(hiddenElement);
    $(form).submit(); 
}
//C#
[HttpPost]
public void submitFormData(MyModel model) {
    System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
    model.Attribute = nvc["attributeName"];
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this isn't *easiest* and it is ugly as well. Besides, why don't use only `append()` instead of creating element with pure JS, if you're already using jQuery ? Another point is that you will have to add the form to the body to get it to work, I think.

Comment: Well, I was trying to get a solely script solution. I would assume one would have a form they could utilize, and if they wanted to they could static in the hidden elements as well. Though I do agree it is ugly.